# export external jar in blackberry but does'nt work

Tags: blackberry, jar

I generated a jar that contain the class which I use in my application, but I add this jar into the project following these steps:

1. right click in the project.
2. properties
3. Build
4. Libraries
5. Add external jars or add jars
6. ok

I can use these libraries as I write my code, but when I'm loading my project in the emulator or device it said that my library "NOT FOUND".

Please help, what is the correct way to use an external jar in blackberry projects?

Comment: There is an option (a CheckBox) for exporting imported jar with the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try following step:

1. right click in the project.
2. properties
3. Build
4. Libraries
5. Add external jars
6. select order and export tab
7. check mark true which .jar file you add
8. click ok

Comment: I can'nt believe you did'nt realize that the steps I put up are the same as you put me. The problem is that these steps do not work, in two cases "Add JARS and Add External JARS". If your read well in the step 5 I describes this step (Add external jars or add jars)

Answer (score 0):

From the [BlackBerry developer docs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Add_jar_dependency_923677_11.jsp):

1. In the Package Explorer view, right-click the project that you want to add a dependency to.
2. Click **Build Path** > **Configure Build Path** .
3. Click the **Libraries** tab.
4. Complete one of the following tasks:

   - Click **Add JARS** if the .jar file is in the current workspace.
   - Click **Add External JARS** if the .jar file is not in the current workspace.
5. Select the .jar file that you want this project to depend on. The .jar file must be generated by a Java® application project. You cannot add a BlackBerry® application project of the Library type in this manner.
6. Click **OK**.

Pay close attention to the two different options in step **4.** above, choosing the one that applies to your situation (where your .jar file is located).

Comment: I can'nt believe you did'nt realize that the steps I put up are the same as you put me. The problem is that these steps do not work, in two cases "**Add JARS** and **Add External JARS**".  If your read well in the step 5 I describes this step (**Add external jars or add jars**)

Comment: @user1519277, you didn't clarify that you understood the difference between the **Add Jars** option and **Add External Jars**, which I added.  You also didn't give us any information about where your .jar file resides.  You asked if you were doing this the right way.  I gave you a link to the official docs (which you didn't indicate that you'd read), so that you could see exactly what the right process is.  That's what you asked.  If it didn't solve the problem, fine.  If you want other people to help you with your problems in the future, I'd recommend being a little more civil.  Good luck.